# How do I route to a new rails controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm new to Rails and have the encountered this problem.

I have a books_controller where I have defined a new action called download:

```
def download
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])

  return send_file @book.get_filepath, :type => 'application/pdf', :filename => @book.get_filename
end
```

My routes.rb is like:

```
resources :books
match '/books(/download(/:id))', :controller => "books", :action => "download"
```

I would like to create a URL like /books/download/10 to call the download action.

I'm not sure how I can create that link. I have tried reading the Rails Guide on routing, but am very confused by it.

I have tried

```
<td><%= link_to books_download_path(book) %></td>
```

and it clearly doesn't work.

```
undefined method `books_download_path' for #<#<Class:0x682ac40>:0x482cad8>
```

I'd appreciate any help on this.

Thanks

P.S. Maybe /books/10/download makes more sense than /books/download/10

index.html.erb

```
<table>
<% @recent_books.each do |book| %>
    <tr>
        <!-- <td><%= image_tag(book.get_thumbnail) %></td> -->
        <td><%= truncate(book.get_title, :length => 30) %></td>
        <td><%= book.get_author %></td>
        <td><%= book.get_summary %></td>
        <td><%= truncate(book.get_filename, :length => 30) %></td>
        <!-- <td><%= link_to 'Download', book %></td> -->
        <td><%= link_to "Download", download_book_path(book) %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
<table>
```

routes.rb

Caliberator::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :authors

```
resources :books do
  get :download, :on => :member, :to => 'books#download'
end
```

end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Rails 3, try this

```
resources :books do
  get :download, :on => :member, :to => 'books#download'
end
```

Now, in your views, you can use.

```
<%= link_to 'Download', download_book_path(book) %>
```

This will generate `books/10/download` type links.

Comment: I have updated my routes to say

    resources :books
    resources :books do
        get :download, :on => :member, :to => "books#download"
    end

and my view says 

    <%= link_to download_book_path(book) %>

But, when I go to /books, I get 

    No route matches {:controller=>"books", :action=>"download"}

But, rake routes shows

    download_book GET    /books/:id/download(.:format) books#download

I am more confused now :(

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You added `resources :books` above the code I suggested. Remove `resources :books` line and retry.

Comment: Hi Kulbir, removing the resources :books doesn't help, I still get the same message on /books

Comment: That's weird. Can you try to restart your rails server, just in case? If it still doesn't work, update your question with `index.html.erb` and `routes.rb` contents.

Comment: For testing, add link to download code to your book's `show.html.erb` and try browsing a book's show page. I feel, there is something wrong with your collection `@recent_books`.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
match '/books(/download(/:id))', :controller => "books", :action => "download", :as => "books_download"
```

Ref:- [naming_routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes)

Comment: Or just `match '/books/:id/download', "reviews#download", :as => "books_download"`

Comment: I get No route matches {:controller=>"books", :action=>"download"}

Comment: Oops sorry its `match '/books/:id/download', "books#download", :as => "books_download"`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I put in. I replaced reviews with books already

Comment: did u restart your server?? Use it something like `book = Book.first` AND `books_download_path(book)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it like this  :

```
<%= link_to "Download", download_books_path + "/#{book.id}" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

For rails 3, you should write:

```
resources :books do
  member do
    get 'download'
  end
end
```